# Changing picture based on its tag value on Mouseover

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I need to show different image on mousehover of `Image`.
Presently i am doing like this

```
 <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <!-- Hover image -->
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="C:\Users\Images\Hi.png"/>
                            </Trigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

It is working fine. But i need to check the `tag` property of the `Image` before showing different picture.
That is, if `Tag` value is 1 i need show `Hi1.png` if its is 2 i need to show `hi2.png`.
I know this can be achieved through code behind by handling `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events of image.
But i want to do it in XAML. Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [MultiDataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger_members(v=vs.90).aspx).

Since DataTrigger operates on associated DataContext/Binding, you need to use Image control.

```
    <Style.Triggers> 
       <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag}" Value="1"/>

        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="C:\Users\Images\Hi1.png"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>

        <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag}" Value="2"/>

        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="C:\Users\Images\Hi2.png"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I have one more doubt, Suppose if i want to check that Tag string contains '2' instead of exact match for '2' (C# equivalent of String.Contains()), how to do that ??

Comment: You can use [BindingConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a UserControl that allows you to change the color of the image on MouseOver. There's a rectangle that uses two SolidColorBrush styles to toggle the colors and displays the image as an OpacityMask.

This a) allows you to make any image any color of your choosing, and b) takes care of you having to rewrite the event logic each time you need a new button.

Note: Source must be set in code as it cannot be bound directly in XAML.

ImageButton.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageButton"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Width="Auto"
        Height="Auto" 
        Cursor="Hand">
    <Rectangle x:Name="Border">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <ImageBrush/>
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource ImageHoverBackground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource ImageBackground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
</UserControl>
```

ImageButton.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class ImageButton : UserControl
    {
        public static DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnSourceChanged));
        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get
            {
                return (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
            }
        }
        private static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject Object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton Button = Object as ImageButton;
            var ImageBrush = Button.Border.OpacityMask as ImageBrush;
            ImageBrush.ImageSource = Button.Source;
        }

        public ImageButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```